# How to show row for non existing value

Tags: mysql

I have a query

```
 SELECT COUNT(*) as total, sales_dept FROM receipts
 WHERE receipts.sales_dept IN ('co', 'cl', 'wi')
 GROUP BY receipts.sales_dept`
```

Which produces the result:

```
total sales_dept
1     co  
5     cl
```

But the result that I want is:

```
total sales_dept
1     co  
5     cl
0     wi
```

I try using values to left join but result still the same

```
SELECT COUNT(*) as total, sales_dept FROM receipts 
LEFT JOIN (
   SELECT 'co' AS val
   UNION ALL
   SELECT 'cl'
   UNION ALL
   SELECT 'wi'
) s on `receipts`.`sales_dept` = `s`.`val`
WHERE `receipts`.`sales_dept` IN ('co', 'cl', 'wi')
GROUP BY `receipts`.`sales_dept`
```

Answer (score 0):

1) Just change `left` by `right` in your second query because you want all values of the query placed *"at right"* of the `join` word.

2) Remove `where`. It is already filtered by join.

```
SELECT COUNT(*) as total, sales_dept FROM receipts 
RIGHT JOIN (
   SELECT 'co' AS val
   UNION ALL
   SELECT 'cl'
   UNION ALL
   SELECT 'wi'
) s on `receipts`.`sales_dept` = `s`.`val`
GROUP BY `receipts`.`sales_dept`
```

Comment: it works but when i add some filter like 
where `receipts`.`date` between '2017-01-01' and '2019-12-12' 
the result back again
and i just realize that wi come out but the count is 1